# When flutter web is open user can not see firebase push notification

Tags: flutter, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

`

```
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-app.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-messaging.js");
firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: '',
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
    const promiseChain = clients
        .matchAll({
            type: "window",
            includeUncontrolled: true
        })
        .then(windowClients => {
            for (let i = 0; i < windowClients.length; i++) {
                const windowClient = windowClients[i];
                windowClient.postMessage(payload);
            }
        })
        .then(() => {
            return registration.showNotification("New Message");
        });
    return promiseChain;
});
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
    const clickedNotification = event.notification;
      clickedNotification.close();

      // Add your custom logic for handling the click
      // For example, you can open a specific URL or perform an action.
      const notificationData = event.notification.data;
      const actionUrl = notificationData.url || '/'; // Define the URL to open on click
      clients.openWindow(actionUrl);
});

`
```

this is my service worker file

I'm new to flutter web and I'm just trying to receive firebase push notifications to my flutter web app. Push notifications are receiving when the app is closed and in the background. But when the app is open, push notification is receiving, but it's not showing the alert notification (I want to show the push notification title and body as an alert in my app if it's opened). Here's my code for it.